# ejabberd 19.09 installed on windows 10, admin page gives 404 page not found

Tags: server, console, windows-10, admin, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd from the windows installer on the ejabberd website. I installed it with admin privelages. It finished with no errors. I clicked on the 'start jabber' executable, and it gave a feedback that jabber is started in the console.
Afterwards it automatically opened a local HTML file telling me to go to http://localhost:5280/admin and enter my username and password which I previously set up. Cool, so I go there and I get 404 not found.
I tried on internet explorer and chrome.
I opened the log folder and found there is no log for errors, only the one from installation..
Anyone has made ejabebrd work on windows 10?

Thank you

Comment: "and enter my username"... I guess you mean the full Jabber ID, not only the username. Maybe the default ejabberd configuration file doesn't have 5280 port open? Or that port is set for tls, so you have to visit https website?

Comment: Yes by username I meant Jabber id. I changed to https like you said and the error message changed to : 
Cannot securely connect to this page
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Im searching for the configuration file now

Comment: Ok what I see is that the conf folder is entirely missing
It should be here as per the install log file:
Unpacking C:\Program Files\ejabberd-19.09\conf\ejabberd.yml

Comment: So after mulitple uninstall/ install, and restart of the computer, I uinstalled v 19.09 and I installed  v19.08. Now I am getting a new messaged when I enter http://localhost:5280/admin  which is ''Host not served''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been identified in github and has been fixed by the contributors.